# Dojo: Dialog refreshing a dojox.layout.ContentPane in a TabContainer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dojo

I have a problem with Dojo in Internet explorer 7/8 (this works fine in Firefox).

Basically I have a tab container with a number of tabs in it (these are dojox.layout.ContentPane's).  On one of these tabs I want to have a "comments box" which would popup a dialog and ask the user to put something in.  The comment is then saved by an call to the back end and I want the tab to reload to show the new comment.

The logic of my save button works something like this:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIcon dijitIconSave', showLabel: true" title="Add your comment">Add Comment
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
      require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom)
      {
        var tText = dijit.byId('comment_70').get('value');
        if (tText == '')
        {
          alert('You have not entered any comment');
          return;
        }
        var tJSONRPC = new JSONRpcClient('JSON-RPC');
        try
        {
          tJSONRPC.be.addComment('70', tText);
          var tTab = dijit.byId('Detail_70');
          tTab.refresh();
        }
        catch (Ex)
        {
          alert(Ex);
        }
      });
    </script></button>
```

Does not appear to be terrible taxing (the 70 at the end is the ID so that the user can have more than one of these open at the same time, hence the tabs).

As mentioned this works fine in Firefox but not in IE 8/7, it throws an error in some of the generated code within dojo (_32.focus(); to be precise), the error message I get in the debug console is "Unexpected call to method or property access"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with your line `tTab.refresh();`:

```
setTimeout(function() { tTab.refresh(); }, 0); // whenIdle
```

Its nearly impossible to tell where the thrown exception comes from - you should use the developement dojo-1.M.m-**src**/dojo/dojo.js code so optimized function- and variable-names are expanded (along with useful commenting once you step-through-debug).

Reason for the above is to eliminate, that exception occurs while handling button onclick-focus event (refresh will tear down DOM in the tab - along with your button)

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?